# Total sales of each region in Northwind database of SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

How can i calculate the total sales of each region in `Northwind` database of SQL Server?
I've ran bellow queries:

1)

```
 select sum( od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice ), v.rid from  
         Orders o , [Order Details] od  , (select et.EmployeeID eid, r.RegionID rid from  region r, territories t , EmployeeTerritories et  
                 where r.RegionID = t.RegionID and et.TerritoryID = t.TerritoryID    ) v
         where od.OrderID = o.OrderID and v.eid = o.EmployeeID
         group by v.rid;
```

2)

```
select sum(b) from
 (select sum(aa.UnitPrice * aa.Quantity)   b
 from region r, territories t , EmployeeTerritories et ,
    (select o.EmployeeID , od.Quantity , od.UnitPrice from  
         Orders o , [Order Details] od
        where od.OrderID = o.OrderID ) aa
 where
    t.regionid = r.regionid and 
    et.TerritoryID = t.TerritoryID and 
    et.EmployeeID  = aa.EmployeeID
    group by r.RegionID) x;
```

3)

```
select sum (Quantity * UnitPrice) from [Order Details];
```

If you run these queries you can see that the third sum is not equal to first one! It means that we have some repeated records in every region!

Comment: use inner join to avoid duplication

Answer (score 1):

In table `EmployeeTerritories` one Employee can have more territories, so when you join on it you multiply all records for each Employee - even if all the territories of each employee belongs to single Region.

You have to use subquery with `GROUP BY` to find `RegionID` for each Employee first, then join on that instead of `EmployeeTerritories`

Something like this for your query A

```
WITH CTE_EmpRegion AS 
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(RegionID) RegionID
    FROM dbo.EmployeeTerritories et 
        INNER JOIN territories t ON t.TerritoryID = et.TerritoryID
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
)
SELECT RegionID, SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice) 
FROM Orders o 
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    INNER JOIN CTE_EmpRegion er ON o.EmployeeID = er.EmployeeID
GROUP BY RegionID
```

[Also you should not be using old-style JOINS which are outdated for more than 20 years now.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding your tables it's difficult to give you a solid answer, but your queries look like they could be cleaned up. Look at INNER JOINs. They will simplify your life exponentially. Implicit Joins are hard to read and debug (what you're doing with parentheses), while explicit joins are tremendously easy to read. It doesn't take long to learn either:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

If you are tracking sales by region, your table should be the same to prevent duplicates from popping up. Otherwise you will quickly have a nightmare on your hands. Also, if the only variable is region, you should be able to use the same query to pull region information. Something like this should be all you need:

```
SELECT SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice) total_sales FROM [Order Details] od
INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.orderID = od.orderID
INNER JOIN EmployeeTerritories et ON et.employeeID=od.employeeID
INNER JOIN Regions t ON t.regionID = et.regionID
INNER JOIN Territories t ON t.regionID = r.regionID
WHERE t.regionID=?
```

Again, I have not seen your table so I had to take a leap of faith that you have employeeID in your Order Detail list. You need a way to join that table that links to a table you've already established in your DB. That's why I suggested INNER JOINs... They will let you see the table structure more easily and help you debug sooner. This sort of table will work just by you putting in a new regionID. That simple.

Let me know how it works or share more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to solve this problem.

```
USE Northwind;
GO 
WITH    EmployeeSales
          AS ( SELECT   e.EmployeeID ,
                        e.LastName ,
                        SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice) ESales
               FROM     dbo.Employees AS e
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.[Order Details] AS od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
               GROUP BY e.EmployeeID ,
                        e.LastName
             ),
        EmployeeRegion
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        EmployeeID ,
                        r.RegionID ,
                        RegionDescription
               FROM     dbo.Region AS r
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Territories AS t ON r.RegionID = t.RegionID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTerritories AS et ON t.TerritoryID = et.TerritoryID
             )
    SELECT  EmployeeRegion.RegionID ,
            EmployeeRegion.RegionDescription ,
            SUM(EmployeeSales.ESales) RegionTotalSale
    FROM    EmployeeSales
            INNER JOIN EmployeeRegion ON EmployeeSales.EmployeeID = EmployeeRegion.EmployeeID
    GROUP BY EmployeeRegion.RegionID ,
            EmployeeRegion.RegionDescription
```

1. ***EmployeeSales***: total sales for each Employee.
2. ***EmployeeRegion***: find `regionID` for each Employee.
3. ***Finally***, Group By `RegionID` and use `SUM()` function to find each region total sales.
   [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEo9N.png)